# Convert jsx to react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Suppose I have a component called 'MyComponent', and I want to store it in a variable of type 'MyComponent' in typescript but use the JSX element to initialise it, something like:

```
let comp: MyComponent = <MyComponent somePropInit={3} />
```

The above code generates errors like:

> 'property 'componentDidMount' is missing in type 'Element'

Actual component I'm using:

```
export class PlayCard extends React.Component<AllCardProps, {}> {
    addToDeck(){...}
```

how I'm trying to store it (I've tried many different things including using typeof, Card.PlayCard, PlayCard , etc):

```
import * as Card from './PlayCard'
...
let c: Card.PlayCard = <PlayCard Id={32} />
```

^ if I try the above I get an error

> 'Property 'addToDeck' is missing in type 'Component<...>'

If I delete addToDeck the error moves on to the next function down. Looks like any function which exists throws it off somehow?

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You may need to wrap it in brackets but you assign a React component to a var like you would any other variable.

Comment: Yeah I get errors such as 'property 'componentDidMount' is missing in type 'Element'

Comment: make sure: `class MyComponent extends React.Component {}`

Comment: Can you share the type of `MyComponent` and sample component? You can also create a snippet in your question. Notice `<>` icon in editor. Also check `babel` checkbox

Comment: added more details about the exact types I'm using if it helps...

Comment: Should this: `<PlayCard` not be `<Card.PlayCard`?

Comment: I tried 'import {PlayCard} from './PlayCard' -> c :PlayCard = <PlayCard..., didn't work either, it also broke the JSX.Element because now it expected all the props to be accounted for as it wasn't using the connect export.

Comment: I've also tried let card: typeof PlayCard

Comment: @tweetypi If you see my answer, there is nothing wrong with TS or React. You must have an interface that is causing the issue. If not, go to `nonde_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts` and check if everything is fine.

Comment: @Rajesh I tried with a stateless/propless component with no luck either, might be my compiler settings?

Comment: Try using `React.RreactNode` as type instead.

Comment: I just updated my question, it looks like react doesn't like my component having a function..

Answer (score 0):

Life-cycle methods for a React component are optional values.

Following is the sample for interface:

```js
interface ComponentLifecycle < P, S > {
    /**
     * Called immediately before mounting occurs, and before `Component#render`.
     * Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
     */
    componentWillMount ? () : void;
    /**
     * Called immediately after a compoment is mounted. Setting state here will trigger re-rendering.
     */
    componentDidMount ? () : void;
```

So the error is not in React/typescript. You might have used an interface that is causing issue.

#### Reference:

- [@Types/React/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts): refer line no. 355.